# adding array values to certain tags

Tags: javascript, arrays

quick question,
I have array as an example of

```
var a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
```

I am trying to take the values of this array and using .html add them to the p tag in the format of 1 - 6

```
$("#existorders").html("There are currently these levels: " + arrayeventslevel.join(', '));
```

the above of course doesn't do what I need, it just lists all values separated by the comma. Question is how can I list them as 1 - 6. Thanks

Comment: Possibly `a[0] + ' - ' + a[a.length - 1]` or `Math.min.apply(Math, a) + ' - ' + Math.max.apply(Math, a)`.

Comment: Something like that? `var levelsRange = a[0] + "-" + a[a.length-1];
$("#existorders").html("There are currently these levels: " + levelsRange);`

Comment: thank you, I used your ideas and came up with what I neede

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a string with the text and the first and last element of the array then insert it into the p using .text(). Also - if its always a numeric array with 1 at the start - you could forget getting the elements of the array and simply get the length of the array.

```js
var a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
var str="There are currently these levels: ";
  str+= a[0] +" - " + a[a.length-1];

$("#existorders").text(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="existorders">/<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, like this?

EDIT: Note the second block needs `marks` around it, but it wouldn't let me escape them.

`$("#existorders").html("There are currently these levels: " + ${arrayeventslevel[0]} - ${arrayeventslevel[arrayeventslevel.length - 1]});`

or actually generating six p tags with requisite numbers?

Comment: thank you I used your suggestion and came up with what I needed